# Fabric JS update rx and ry for an object?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.JS to create a layout builder. However once the object is displayed on canvas I cannot update the rx and ry property of the object like rectangle. I have a used a slider field where the user uses a slider for updating value of rx and ry on the object.

Further when I view the object it has been updated but the canvas is not updated with the new value of rx and ry.

Following is the code snippet I use :

```
$('#slider').slider()
                .on('slideStop', function (ev) {

                    var val = $('#slider').slider('getValue').val();
                    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
                    if (activeObject) {
                        console.log('Inside active object');
                        activeObject.set({'rx': val, 'ry': val});
                        canvas.renderAll();
                    } 
        });
```

Comment: please be sure to parseInt number.

Comment: Tried your solution @AndreaBogazzi but it did not make any difference.!

Comment: are you using jquery ui slider??

Comment: Yes I am using jquery ui slider to update the values rx and ry of a rectangle.

Comment: there was a version of fabric 1.7.x that was not considering rx ry for cache. are you using latest?

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

$("#slider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    max: 50,
    slide: refreshSwatch,
    change: refreshSwatch
});

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 25,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    height: 150
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 225,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    fill: 'rgba(100,100,200,0.5)'
}));
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.on('object:selected',function(){
 $("#slider").slider('value',canvas.getActiveObject().rx);
})

function refreshSwatch() {
    var val = $("#slider").slider("value");
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (activeObject) {
        activeObject.set({
            'rx': val,
            'ry': val
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Probably I am not getting what is your actual issue, but I added a demo and from jQuery slider value, its updating rect rx,ry value.